# Problem with Master pages event order

Tags: asp.net

I have a simple setup with the master page housing some controls used by all child pages.

I found when moving to new pages the master page page loads event fires as a non post back and read the solution was to store it's current values somewhere for retrieval.  Ok all done.

The child page uses these values to run a report. When I switch to a new report, all is well.  If I change the values in the master page the master page and the sub page load events fire.

The load event for the sub page fires first, picks up the values from the master page which are still the old values and then finally the master page events fire and all the new values are stored.  The report hasn't changed as it still ran from the old values.

I can't really see a way around this. All you ever hear is that master pages are a saving grace but I swear i've never jumped through so many hoops to get a page to load correctly.

And now this!

Anyone see a plan to resolve it?

Comment: I have jumped a massive hoop to correct this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Populating the controls during the Masterpage's Init will solve your issue from the sounds of it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3.aspx

An alternate approach would be to have a public sub in the content page(s) that you can call from the masterpage during load which in effect acts as an alternate to the page load event.

Comment: No the state is still the old value as this isn't updated until the textChanged event fires which is after all the page loads and inits. So I tried updating in the text init but the textbox always appears empty at this stage.  More hoop jumping :)

Comment: I saw an excellent hoop to jump through but also have found that on the page load the text property on the control is blank despite having a value.  I think this is due to it being a date extender from the ajax toolkit.

Comment: An alternate approach would be to have a public sub in the content page(s) that you can call from the masterpage during load which in effect acts as an alternate to the page load event ........ Done

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more indepth look at the page lifecycle when using masterpages:

http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2009/03/08/asp-net-page-events-lifecycle.aspx